# boost::make_shared causing crashes in 64-bit system

Tags: c++, boost, shared-ptr, smart-pointers

I have a C++ program which previously ran on 32-bit system and now runs on 64-bit system. The code uses boost library extensively including smart pointers, data containers, etc. However since the transition to 64-bit system, specifically in the case of `shared_ptr` when trying to create the pointer using `boost::make_shared`, I am observing several crashes due to `SIGSEGV` or `SIGBUS`. The backtrace isn't much of help but after replacing

```
boost::shared_ptr<MyClass> myPtr = boost::make_shared<MyClass>();
```

by

```
boost::shared_ptr<MyClass> myPtr(new MyClass());
```

it works without any segfault or core.

I understand that `make_shared` avoids a memory allocation for the shared counter, because a single memory chunk will be used for the counter and the `MyClass` object, but I am unable to understand why this issue is caused specifically for 64-bit system as it worked perfectly fine on 32-bit system.

Any explanation regarding this behaviour is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**
The code also works if `boost::shared_ptr` is completely replaced by `std::shared_ptr`. Not sure if the issue is specifically with boost since upgrading of boost library to latest version didn't help as well.

Comment: This sounds like some undefined behavior caused by something else. Did you try using address sanitizer, thread sanitizer or undefined behavior sanitizer to check what else you're doing wrong? For example, you maybe be using something after it's deleted, or writing outside the boundaries of a vector or array.

Comment: I agree the backtrace isn't of much help, because ... it's missing. Of course, you need to minimize the code to be selfcontained, but if you can't, at **least** include the information you couldn't figure out. My crystal ball tells me it might be a data race. Are you using threads?

Comment: This sounds like heap corruption caused by some error in your code, rather than anything specifically caused by `shared_ptr`. Probably your code was bugged all along, but the bug only manifest on switching to a 64 bit platform. You should forget about how the code used to work and how something or other must be to blame, instead just keep an open mind and track down the bug as you would any other.

Comment: My guess would be writing out of the bounds of the object, with `boost::shared_ptr<MyClass> myPtr(new MyClass())` there's probably nothing important next to the object but with `boost::shared_ptr<MyClass> myPtr = boost::make_shared<MyClass>()` the shared pointer state is next to your object causing a more immediate crash. Try using address sanitizer

Comment: @sehe I would have gladly share the backtrace if I could, but sadly I can't share it. The code does use threads.

Comment: Good luck tracing the source of your [Undefined Behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), As others have suggested, chances are good that you'll spot more leads using sanitizers or thread checkers (like dbrd or helgrind).

Comment: @john Can you please let me know the causes of heap corruption, since the codebase is too large and complex, its tough to understand where exactly the heap corruption occurs.

Comment: @HrishikeshBawane Nobody can answer that without the information (code/traces). We already told you all the causes and methods to track them: they will be heap corruption (use sanitizers), data races (use thread checkers or code review) or both.

Comment: @HrishikeshBawane There are many possible causes. Code elimination is a long winded but fairly reliable technique. Assuming you can reproduce the error fairly easily then try removing sections of code, just have them return dummy results instead. If suddenly after removing some code the bug stops happening then the bug is in or related to the section of code just removed.

Comment: @john sadly that isn't true in the case of UB. Point in case: the code **appeared to work** in 32-bit mode. Or when avoiding `make_shared`. Both are almost _certainly_ not causes. So, what you need is to isolate the cause by eliminating **irrelevant** factors. That's tedious, so going with static analysis/instrumentation first is more natural.